# Highcharts - Drill up event to toggle the displayed information back

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Please consider this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/prashu421/5Lzskkwg/1/
I have a pie chart, which drills down into a Bar chart, now when I drill down I want to display a table, which is working fine if only one static table is used.

However, I want to display different table based on different pie selection.
I mean, say we have a pie with three slices A, B, C and there exists corresponding bar charts X, Y, Z, and tables 1, 2, 3 where X and 1 is displayed upon clicking A, Y and 2 on B, and Z and 3 on C

I am able to drill down successfully, but I am unable to drill up back, can anyone help me with the same.

Here's the code I have problem with -

```
events: {
            drilldown: function(e) {
            if( e.point.name == 'Chrome' ){
                var tableToggle = 1;
                exampleTable1.toggle();
              } else {
                var tableToggle = 2;
                exampleTable2.toggle();
              }
                  },
             drillup: function() {
              if(tableToggle == 1){
                exampleTable1.toggle();
              } else {
                exampleTable2.toggle();
              }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/teLuz102/ . console error -> Uncaught ReferenceError: tableToggle is not defined

Comment: I think that was the issue, now it works fine, just had to remove "var" in the drill down and drill up functions, thanks much for that @Deep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to this fiddle here - 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lyzy0syd/

Replace your code with the below code,

```
       events: {
        drilldown: function(e) {
        if( e.point.name == 'Chrome' ){
            tableToggle = 1;
            exampleTable1.toggle();
          } else {
            tableToggle = 2;
            exampleTable2.toggle();
          }
              },
         drillup: function() {
          if(tableToggle == 1){
            exampleTable1.toggle();
          } else {
            exampleTable2.toggle();
          }
        }
    }
```